# Access a variable inside watch by a directive in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, watch

I am new to angular and having some trouble with watch. I am watching a variable inside a controller. Once the variable's value has changed, I want to send this changed value to a directive.

Here is the watch function:

```
$scope.$watch("comboDetail", function(newValue, oldValue) {
  $scope.overlayProductCard = $scope.comboDetail.collectionCd;
  console.log("$scope.overlayProductCardWithinWatch", $scope.overlayProductCard);
}
```

And my directive: (clipped for the sake of reading)

```
return {
scope: {
      productCard: '='
    },
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: appVersionFactory.getViewBaseUrl() + '/assets/partials/tv/tv-overlay-link.html',
    replace: true,
    link: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {
      console.log("$scope.productCard", $scope.productCard);

  };
```

However, `$scope.productCard` returns undefined to me whereas `$scope.overlayProductCardWithinWatch` returns me the right data.

How do I receive this data in the directive?

Comment: In your html how are you passing productCard to your directive? 2 way binding should take care of updating the directive's `productCard` so you don't need to do anything to "pass it in". The `console.log` function in your directive runs when the directive is first created and productCard is `undefined`. It's probably being set to a value at some later point in time

Comment: should have wrote in the question, but here is my HTML: <tv-overlay-link product-card="overlayProductCard"> </tv-overlay-link>

Comment: that looks good. so when you change your controller's `$scope.overlayProductCard` it will automatically set the directive's `$scope.productCard`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say I have directive like `<test param="controllerParam"></test>` with template `<div>{{param}}</div>`.If I change `controllerParam` in controller, I do not need to watch/something else - directive will gain new value. If I want to log new value in directive each time it changes - then I need watch in directive.

Link function executes once per element, so you log value of variable only once. (initial one)

Comment: Good insight! Thank you.  I didnt know that link is executed once per element. I am using a template to generate directive HTML and I do not want to display overlayProductCard as is. I need to manipulate the data before posting. In such a case, what should I do?

Comment: You can use filter in html - this looks pretty or use watch in directive for better perfomance for large arrays etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
link: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {
  scope.$watch('productCard', function (newValue) {
    console.log("$scope.productCard", newValue);
  })
};
```

and before that pass `productCard` from your element tag in HTML, Like :
`data-product-card="overlayProductCard"`